# Ajax call not working in foreach loop in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm dynamically adding data to the database using AJAX and displaying them using `foreach` loop in MVC, I have also added a button to remove the those data using ajax call.

**HTML/MVC code:**

```
<div id="divaddrules" class="form-group row">
   @try
      {
         foreach (var item in ViewBag.AdditionalRules)
           {
             <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p style="font-size:large">@item.AdditionalDesc</p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="button" onclick="Removeinput(@item.id)" class="text-dark" style="border:none; background-color:transparent" value="X" />
              </div>
            }
       }
       catch (Exception ex){ }

</div>
```

Now when I click on Remove button it call the following JS code:

```
function Removeinput(id) {
        var datas = {};
            datas.addId = id
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Rooms/RemoveAdditionalRules",
            type: "GET",
            data: datas,
            success: function (result) {
               alert(result.id);
               $("#divaddrules").load(window.location.href + " #divaddrules");
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error: " + result.status);
           }
        });
}
```

and its passing to this controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult RemoveAdditionalRules(int addId)
{
     HouseRules rules = db.HouseRules.Find(addId);
     db.HouseRules.Remove(rules);
     db.SaveChanges();

     return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

> I'm getting 500 error on ajax call error.

Can anyone tell me where I'm doing it wrong? Please.. I'm stuck here.

Update: 
Attached screenshot: [Debug Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu4N6.png)

Comment: `return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` => actually you're not returning any JSON data, this maybe the cause of your 500 error. Try `return Json(new { id = addId }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`.

Comment: Are you able to hit the server?

Comment: i think you have created a model for data to pass, and in action you have taken as parameter

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I tried, but still the same error!

Comment: @RamSingh I didn't get you...

Comment: @GautamSharma, instead of creating model, just pass data in query string with URL

Comment: @RamSingh ok let me try!

Comment: Try removing `AuthorizeAttribute` (`[Authorize]`). Is the same error still occurs? Sometimes in console the AJAX call returns HTML tags which explains the error. Also try `data: { addId: id },` too.

Comment: @RamSingh Nope, it didn't worked.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I tried still making changes.. but its returning the null value

Comment: Is that `result.id` returns null or undefined (together with `addId` has value of zero because it's non-nullable)? Or the data is not deleted by `db.HouseRules.Remove(rules)`?

Comment: the problem it is missing values on db, in the image you ask to **id 25** but return **null** and you try to remove a item passing null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your `Removeinput` function as follows:

```
function Removeinput(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Rooms/RemoveAdditionalRules",
            type: "GET",
            data: { addId : id},
            success: function (response) {
               alert(response);
               $("#divaddrules").load(window.location.href + " #divaddrules");
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error: " + result.status);
           }
        });
}
```

Then in the controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult RemoveAdditionalRules(int addId)
{
     AdditionalRules rules = db.AdditionalRules.Find(addId); // Here was the problem. He was pointing to the wrong table that has fixed over team viewer.
     db.AdditionalRules.Remove(rules);
     db.SaveChanges();

     return Json(addId,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: @GautamSharma Have you debugged it properly? Does `addId` value pass to the controller method?

Comment: `HouseRules rules = db.HouseRules.Find(addId)` => if this returns empty result (null), certainly `db.HouseRules.Remove(rules)` will throw argument exception since `Remove` doesn't accept null argument.

Comment: @GautamSharma I have updated my answer. check both `Removeinput` method and Controller method.

Comment: @GautamSharma Can you share team viewer Id and pass? I am solving your problem!

Comment: What version you are using? My uid: 1063816751 and pass: 1457

Comment: @GautamSharma Very glad to helping you!

Answer (score 0):

the problem it is missing values on db, in the image you ask to id 25 but return null and you try to remove a item passing null value.

so in your case you need to validate before remove or fix the missing data:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult RemoveAdditionalRules(int addId)
{
     HouseRules rules = db.HouseRules.Find(addId);

If(rules == null)
{
  //return error msg.
  return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
     db.HouseRules.Remove(rules);
     db.SaveChanges();

     return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

make your input type submit, may this was helpful

```js
function deleterelation(id) {
    debugger;
    if (id > 0)
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Relations/Delete/" + id,
            type: "get",
            datatype: "json",
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                if (response != null) {
                    

                    $("#txtDName").text(response.name);
                    $("#DRelationId").val(response.id);
                    $("#DeleteRelation").modal("show");
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {

                $("#DeleteRelationLoading").hide();
                $("#DeleteRelation_btn_cancel").show();
                $("#DeleteRelation_btn_save").show();
            }
        });
    else
        toastr.error("Something went wrong");
}
```

```
<input type="submit" onclick="Removeinput(@item.id)" class="text-dark" style="border:none; background-color:transparent" value="X" />
```

if this not work plz let me know

Comment: this is not a solution

Comment: may  this is the problem
check your model id and Removeinput(@item.id) is same

Comment: you are not sending your url to id
use
`url: "/Relations/Delete/" + id,
            type: "get",
            datatype: "json",
            data: { id: id },
`